# How to Print Multi-Step Form After Adding Values

Tags: jquery, html, forms, printing

I have a new multi-step form in development that needs to do the following:

1. Gather user entered field values
2. Print the values as entered and using a print style sheet
3. Email results to a specific address
4. Save the values to a database

What's the overall process for this? Also, could you provide code examples?

Please refer to my [current form](http://new-site.autouplinktech.com/forms/form-video360.html) to see what it is doing so far. A solution involving Jquery is preferred; I cannot use any PHP. Thanks!

Comment: Last time I checked Javascript can't send emails or save values to a database. Though there was a time when JS couldn't render PDFs so who knows what the kids have cooking these days.

Comment: @Will I know javascript can't do all that, but just thought it should be included somewhere.

Comment: You're going to have problems with requirements 3+4 without using a server side language like PHP.